# How do I revoke my OpenPGP keys if I do not have access to my private key?

Tags: key-management, openpgp

I have lost access to my PGP Private Key. However I still have the revocation certificate, the passphrase (and the public key).

Is it possible to revoke my key pair from the Public Key Servers using this information? If so, what are the steps?

I tried looking this up but this does not seem to be well-documented anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you import your public key into your keyring, if not already there, then the revokation certificate.

```
gpg --import my_key.asc
gpg --import my_revocation.txt
```

Your key is then revoked locally. You just need to push this to the keyservers.

```
gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --send-keys [YOUR_KEY_ID]
```